# Masonry is not arranging the images

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, masonry

I am attempting to arrange some (rather big) images using masonry, however the code below does not seem to be working. I am using **node.js** with express and installed the **masonryjs** package and attempted it that way which didn't seem to work, I then tried using the cdn with the same result.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>web</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <!-- Styleheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
      </head>
            
      <!-- masonry JS-->
      <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/3.0.4/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
             
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var elem = document.querySelector('.grid');
        var msnry = new Masonry( elem, {
          // options
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          columnWidth: 200
        });
      </script>
            
      <style>
        .grid-item { width:10% }
      </style>
              
      <body>
        <div class='grid'>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="images/photo/cat1/c11.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="images/photo/cat1/c12.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="images/photo/cat1/c13.png" alt=""></div>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="images/photo/cat1/c14.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="images/photo/cat1/c15.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your script to just before  ***or*** change the script to

```
$(function() {
    var elem = document.querySelector('.grid');
    var msnry = new Masonry( elem, {
        // options
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        columnWidth: 200
    });
});
```

Pretty sure you're running the script before the document is ready.